# Discriminate MOS from BJT easily

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, multimeter

I have a transistor for which no datasheet is available

the transistor is supposed to be NPN (which implies BJT).

(BD247C-Transistor-NPN, 100V 25A, 120W in TO220)

how can I find out easily if it's a MOS or if it's a BJT?

I have a Digital multi meter and a +5,+12V power supply.

[image: TI 8206 BD147C]

Comment: "NPN" in the name is a dead giveaway, as BJTs can either be on NPN or PNP topology. MOS as you say, or MOSFETs, are either N-Channel or P-Channel topology.

Comment: You are right! But NPN is not printed on the casing!! It's just an info from the seller, which might have confused NPN with N-Channel

Comment: As an aside, 120W dissipation in a TO-220 sounds... optimistic :P

Comment: Anze--, okay, in a more general sense it would be a very hard process to "check" which it is. You would need a bench power supply, a variety of resistors, the ability to reverse-polary the setup (in order to check for PNP/P-Channel versions), a multimeter, and be willing to potentially blow up a few. On top of that, without the datasheet, it would be impossible to know the maximum ratings, \$ V_{gs(th)} \$ if it is a MOSFET, and other information you really need in order to properly (and safely!) use it in a design. So your question is something that should never really be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Google the part number.  I just did, and while I didn't find a data sheet, I did find an NTE cross-reference (for an NPN).  This indicates that it's an obsolete consumer part.
2. Measure each leg against the others with the meter in diode mode.

   1. An NPN will show the base-emitter and base-collector junctions as one diode drop if the base is positive (and if it's a *really* old transistor you'll learn whether it's silicon or germanium).
   2. A PNP will look like an NPN, only in reverse.
   3. A typical MOSFET will look like an open-circuit from gate to either source or drain.  It *may* look like a diode drop from source to drain (for an N-channel) or from drain to source (for a P-channel) or it may be open, or (if it's depletion mode) it may look like a resistor.  If you really think it's a MOSFET you can try putting 10V or so on the suspected gate-source pins and see if the drain-source pins conduct.
   4. A 3-terminal voltage regulator will just look odd

Comment: I will follow up with the results, just for record purposes!!